# How to find/identify bad connections in house wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Is there a way to identify bad connections that are still connected but are prone to overheating (loose screw, badly applied wire nut, etc)?

I just moved in a newly built house and started to wonder if those kind of things could be identified or perceived before some outlet start melting due to a loose wire somewhere in the circuit.

PS: I'm not expecting it to happen. Neither I think that the electrical was poorly done, but I've seen that happen more than once in properly done wiring...

Comment: Do you want to catch a bad connection *in the act* of overheating, or *before* it overheats?

Comment: I want to know if it possible to find it before it overheats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I would know how to do it is to go and buy an inexpensive Infrared Thermometer. You can buy them anywhere for less than $60.00. Then you can walk through and "site" any device that appear to be warmer than normal. Start with you panel and survey every breaker. Then you can go to every device and check it. Did I mention you should make sure the circuit is on a load for at least an hour. I would use a small 1500W heater for a load source on receptacles. This is something you can do over time. If you are just shooting a receptacle head or an AC disconnect the temperature should rise to at least 5 - 10 degrees above normal temp. Really loose connections will rise much more than that.

Comment: Will those infrared thermometer "see" through drywall or outlet "covers"? I think the outlets would be where the problems would happen since the wire ends are screwed there, and many have derivations with wirenuts or within the screws of the outlets itself.

Answer (score 2):

### New tech makes this easy.  Install Arc Fault breakers.

There are circuit breakers specifically designed to detect the conditions you are talking about.  They contain a small digital signal processor that listens for the telltale sound of arcing.  I talk like it's a sound, it really is - if you've ever had a loose connection on a speaker or headphone, you've heard it.

They are called AFCI breakers.

I imagine in a new build, your panel isn't CH, QO, or an obsolete panel like Pushmatic...  so the AFCI breakers shouldn't be too expensive, probably in the $30 range.

If the house is super new, there's a good chance some of your breakers are already AFCI.

**This won't hunt down the fault, but it will prevent it from burning your house down.**  when you get a trip, then you take apart each (now dead) outlet and look for trouble.  There's no realistic way to find them in advance as they can develop over time.

If the breaker slot is already occupied by a GFCI breaker, you can either use a combo AFCI/GFCI breaker, or relocate the GFCI function downline to the first receptacle.  Unfortunately AFCI *receptacles* are not common.

All my panels are the kinds where GFCI breakers are prohibitively priced, so I am fond of sticking a junction box 6 inches away from the panel and sticking GFCI receptacles there, then feed the LOAD wires back into the service panel to serve the circuit I'm protecting.

Comment: I don't think those exist in Brazil. At least I couldn't find those by name. What is used (and was used in my new house) is: each circuit is proctect by a thermo-magnetic breaker, those breakers are collective protected by a general residual-current breaker (I think that is the so called GFI), which in turn is connected to a main thermo-magnetic breaker. There is also a surge-protector (it is a devide that detects high tension from lightning and so) after the main breaker in parallel to the residual-current breaker.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue, in Brazil you are using European style voltage, wiring methods, *and identifying names*.  I know they call a GFI/GFCI an RCD/RCBO... I have never heard what they call AFCIs. They must call them something, it's rather unlikely they don't exist, they have the same problems we do, and some countries are a great deal more safety conscious.  Perhaps they have whole-house AFCI, like they do for GFCI.

Comment: According to wikipedia, those do not detect the kind of fault that I'm worried about (high resistance faults due to loose screews or bad junctions). Also I really don't think that those exist in Brazil in any shape or form. I looked into the catalogs of major electrical devices companies and found nothing of the sorts.

Comment: In Europe, Siemens sell Arc Fault Detection Devices (AFDs or AFDDs). Siemens say *"[According to the international standard IEC 60364-4-42, AFD units are strongly recommended all over Europe as the recognized state-of-the-art technology in specific application fields. With the publishing of the standard DIN VDE 0100-420, the installation of AFD units is now mandatory for many locations in Germany.](https://www.siemens.com/global/en/home/products/energy/low-voltage/components/sentron-protection-devices/arc-fault-detection-devices.html)"* - new wooden homes, care-centres for children, elderly...

Comment: @LuizBorges might want to read what Mike Holt has to say on the subject. He too was skeptical.  Mind you this is 15 years ago , they have advanced since.  https://www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/AFCI-HTML/HTML/AFCI_-_Update~20021209.htm